# What is the minimum number of comparisons under best case for KMP Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

What is the minimum number of comparisons under best case scenario for KMP algorithm ?

Comment: 0, if the string you are searching in is empty. Can't think of a better scenario than that.

Comment: Its not constant, its O(n) where n is the length of text, and text length is 0 here, so n = 0.

Comment: It's clearly 0 in this case, but O(n) is not the same as n. For example, n+k (for any constant k) is O(n). O(n) is *only* a statement about limits, not a statement about particular value of n. In any event, KMP is certainly O(n) but in most scenarios the multiplier (for number of compares) is quite a bit less than 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the minimum number of comparisons in best case would be the length of your string, meaning you found a match first try.  The algorithm is O(n), meaning that the upper bound or worst case scenario would take n comparisons where n is the length of the string that you are searching.  The wiki is pretty good.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: What i got from your answer is: If T is a string and P is a pattern, where |T| = n, |P| = m, If total number of shifts are S than at-most shifts will be m-1, and minimum shifts required are 1, IF total number of comparisons are n, than total would be O(n + S), as minimum shifts are 1, than it would be O(n). Example would be if T = xxa, and P = xx, than after first attempt with performing shift of 1 algo stops and total comparisons will be 3 (2 for 'xx' and 1 for a mismatch) ...........Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: There won't be a mismatch in your example because P only has two characters

Comment: At initial alignment, algorithm first reports a match of 'xx' and performs a shift of 1 character to check if there are some other occurrences. After shift T[3] and P[2] will be compared which will be the mismatch and algorithm stops here.   Clearly it is bounded by O(n) where n is the length of the text.

Comment: Normally the algorithm returns the first match so I don't see why you say it checks for T[3]

Comment: Algorithm should report all occurrences of pattern in text, if it stops after reporting the first match, than it will definitely miss all the next occurrences of the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The best case happens when the string you are looking for is located just at the beginning of your text string. In this case, if you are looking for a `k` letter string inside a `n` letter string, the best case number of comparisons would be `k`.

You also have to take into account the overhead of computing the table, based on your `k` letter word, that will allow you to know which letters to skip if you don't find a match. In any case, this construction is done in `O(k)`.

Comment: Say, i have a text and pattern like :
T = xxabc
P = xx

In this case string length is 5 and pattern length is 2, than total comparisons are 4. Would it be the best case, as it does not looks like O(m)

Comment: Where are the four comparisons? You compare T[0] to P[0] then T[1] to P[1] and you're done.